# UK Home office - Lost Landing Card

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa, uk-visa

I applied for Subject Access Request as I had a minor immigration problem with the officer before the last time I entered the Uk. They speculated that I was trying to live in the UK through frequent successive visits but after almost an hour of questioning they let me in. I am applying for a tier 4 residency now and I was trying to find out what the officer wrote on the landing card I sent a SAR and this was the response.
"I am afraid that further searches of our databases have not identified any landing card entries.
I would also like to make you aware that the Home Office border systems hold records of passenger UK entry and exit data only via scheduled commercial routes. The accuracy of the information provided is dependent on the quality of data submitted by the carriers. Any errors or omissions in the data provided will need to be raised with the carrier that provided the information."

Does that mean that they lost the landing card and that I have a clean slate as records of that problematic entry is lost?

Comment: How long ago was "the last time I entered the UK?"

Comment: I am not sure the entry matters much either way. During evaluation of the tier 4 application they are likely to look at your travel history and see the same set of entries and exits.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica the last time I entered the UK was for a short course, it was last September 2019 and I stayed until Feb 2020 for the 5 months short course. The entry was successful and they let me in within a split of a second. The entry which worried me was the one before that last one ( January 2018 ) I stayed for 2 months and left. They questioned for 20-30 minutes but I wasn't placed in a detention or anything I just asked for the landing card to see what the officer wrote and the response from SAR is provided above.